# getValue() returning null from ViewModel (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I have been struggling with one bug for a week now. I am a beginner android developer and I am trying to build MVVM app. The idea is to be gaming news but that does not really matter. Here are my 3 classes that are key to this bug.
My NewsFragment class:

```
    FragmentNewsBinding binding;
    NewsFragmentAdapter adapter;
    Context context;
    public NewsFragmentViewModel newsFragmentViewModel;

    public NewsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        newsFragmentViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NewsFragmentViewModel.class);
        // Inflating the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentNewsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        newsFragmentViewModel.init();
        setAdapter(container);
        observeChanges();
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    }

    private void setAdapter(ViewGroup container) {
        context = container.getContext();
        adapter = new NewsFragmentAdapter(newsFragmentViewModel.getItems().getValue(), context);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        binding.recyclerViewNews.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        binding.recyclerViewNews.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void observeChanges() {


        newsFragmentViewModel.getItems().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Item>>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Item> items) {
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

NewsFragmentViewModel class:

```
public class NewsFragmentViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<List<Item>> mItems;
    private NewsRepository mRepo;

    // Empty constructor
    public NewsFragmentViewModel() {

    }
    public void init() {
        if (mItems != null) {
            return;
        }
        mRepo = NewsRepository.getInstance();
        mItems = mRepo.getItems();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Item>> getItems() {
        return mItems;
    }
}
```

And the repository class:

```
public class NewsRepository {


    MutableLiveData<List<Item>> mItems;
    private static NewsRepository instance;

    public static NewsRepository getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new NewsRepository();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    //Empty constructor
    private NewsRepository() {

    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<Item>> getItems() {
        mItems = new MutableLiveData<>();

        ServiceApi.getInstance().getGamezoneMethods().getGamezoneNews().enqueue(new Callback<Rss>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Rss> call, Response<Rss> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    List<Item> items = response.body().getChannel().getItems();
                    mItems.postValue(items);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Rss> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Failed", "Error");
                mItems.postValue(null);
            }
        });
        return mItems;
    }
}
```

Now, the main problem with this code is that in the repository when I do my request I successfully get the data and I think, I successfully push the data to the viewmodel. But when I try to get my data from the LiveData in the viewmodel class or in the fragment class I always get null, and because of the null problem I cannot set up an adapter properly and I cannot set up my `onChanged()` method. I am trying to get the data in the fragment with the classic `getValue()` method. Please somebody help me because I am losing my mind.
If you are confused with this code, here is [link](https://github.com/Ivan-005/GamingNews-App/tree/gamingApp-branch) to my github repo.

Comment: hi, could it be an issue with the data backing the list

Comment: No, I have done debugginhg and when I test my getters from my model class I always get  good response in the logcat. Data exists but only in the repository and then it somehow vanishes.

Comment: So what's null? Please include the full stack trace.

Comment: In repo, mItems.postValue(items) update value for mItems of the repo, not mItems on the view model. And enqueue(new ...) is an async call (I guess) , so the "return mItems"  would be null

Comment: Yes the getItems() is an async call. I get the idea of what the problem is but can you tell me a fix?

Comment: In repo: newsFragmentViewModel.getItems().postValue(items)

Comment: But can i make a newsFragmentViewModel inside the repo class and if I can from where should I call this method as you suggest. Should I call it inside the async call or outside from it.

Comment: My intention is to replace ```mItems.postValue(items)```, if it works, you can return null or anything at the synchrous return

Comment: Since you have repo using singleton pattern, I have an idea. View, vm and repo all use mItems of repo. In repo: create a variable mItems (you already did, but it should be public). In view model: mItems = mRepo.mItems. Everything else keeps the same.

Comment: Again same error.

Comment: Can you change  initialization of your viewModel. Make it
**newsFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProvider.of(this).get(NewsFragmentViewModel.class);**

Comment: No, I think that command was deprecated and now it tells me that is removed, so I can't even try